# Getting basic information from Instagram using PHP

Tags: php, instagram

```
$url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/XXXX?access_token=XXXX';
echo json_decode(file_get_contents($url))->{'followed_by'};
```

I am using this code and I do not understand what the issue is. I'm new to PHP so excuse the newbie mistake. I'm trying to get the "followed_by" to display on its own. I've managed to get Facebook's "like" and twitter's followers to display this way.

Comment: Sorry, this page isn't available.

Answer (score 29):

In case you need to grab follower count (or other fields) without logging in, Instagram is nice enough to put them in JSON inside the page source:

```
$raw = file_get_contents('https://www.instagram.com/USERNAME'); //replace with user
preg_match('/\"edge_followed_by\"\:\s?\{\"count\"\:\s?([0-9]+)/',$raw,$m);
print intval($m[1]);

//returns "123"
```

Hope that helps.

**24 May 2016** Updated to be more tolerant of spaces in JSON.

**19 Apr 2018** Updated to use new "edge_" prefix.

Comment: After **hours** trying to implement this using the Instagram API, I ended up using this solution. **Thank you**.

Worst API design and documentation I've never seen. You even have to send a _screencast_ explaining what you want to do with the API to get out of sandbox mode. I just want to get the followers count for any given user, which is public information anyways. It's madness.

Comment: Great solution! I currently use it as fallback when the token expires or the api gives up :p

Comment: @Ben This solution worked perfectly for me up until a few weeks ago, I'm guessing Instagram may have changed something on the page? Would you mind checking and updating the solution? I now get an Undefined Offset error (for $m[1]). Thanks!

Comment: @user6122500 Thanks for the heads up. Looks like they've added a prefix to the variable name, so I've updated the sample code above. Glad it's been helpful!

Comment: what about any profile's following count? how many people do they follow.

Comment: @MuneebZulfiqar should be able to replace "edge_followed_by" with "edge_follow".

Comment: Finally it stopped working for me.  If anyone have any workaround, please let me know.

Comment: @MashR. Just ran a test and it's still functioning for me, and IG hasn't changed their output either. Perhaps there's an issue getting the page?

Comment: @Ben , Thanks for your quick reply.  Its working in one website but not working in two other host where i test. I checked the output, instagram is redirecting to login page and its returning the content of login page.

Comment: @MashR. Just a theory, but perhaps those two non-working host IPs have been rate-limited? I'm sure IG is aggressive about that.

Comment: This solution isn't working on serverside. Do anybody has an idea how to get it via serverside (by api?)?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Instagram API Docs](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/), `followed_by` is a child of `counts` which is a child of `data`.

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/1574083/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

Returns:

```
{
"data": {
    "id": "1574083",
    "username": "snoopdogg",
    "full_name": "Snoop Dogg",
    "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_1574083_75sq_1295469061.jpg",
    "bio": "This is my bio",
    "website": "http://snoopdogg.com",
    "counts": {
        "media": 1320,
        "follows": 420,
        "followed_by": 3410
    }
}
```

The following should therefore work.

```
<?php 
$url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/XXXX?access_token=XXXX';
$api_response = file_get_contents($url);
$record = json_decode($api_response);
echo $record->data->counts->followed_by;

// if nothing is echoed try
echo '<pre>' . print_r($api_response, true) . '</pre>';
echo '<pre>' . print_r($record, true) . '</pre>';
// to see what is in the $api_response and $record object
```

Comment: I've just tried the code you've given but it does not work (I've tried both echo's on its own). I've even made sure that my api.instagram.com/xxx is valid and it is.

Comment: @NazarAbubaker - Are you sure that your access_token is correct - how are you generating it?  Try the edited code above and let us know what is actually being returned by the API.

Comment: I used this to generate the access_token [link]http://jelled.com/instagram/access-token[/link]. Taken from [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12677551/how-to-get-access-token-from-instagram-token-using-jquery-or-php[/link]

All I get is "Warning: file_get_contents() [<a href='function.file-get-contents'>function.file-get-contents</a>]: Unable to find the wrapper &quot;https&quot; - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? in XXX on line 36"

Comment: @NazarAbubaker - So what is $api_response showing? And what happens if you manually paste the generated URL into a web browser?

Comment: @NazarAbubaker - For the PHP error, see the comment with 31 upvotes in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444249/unable-to-find-the-wrapper-https-did-you-forget-to-enable-it-when-you-config

Comment: When I paste the URL into a web browser I see all my instagram information. Looking at the error the "file_get_contents" is what is causing the issue

Comment: @NazarAbubaker - well that's good news at least! Looks like your problem is because your PHP configuration does not have the library required to load a https site. So the URL is correct, but PHP cannot retrieve it because it does not have the openssl library.  Editing your PHP config and restarting Apache should work. You may also need to install openssl if you do not have it.

Comment: @PassKit. How we can get all the api response without using pagination?

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

```
<?php 
$instagram = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/xxxxx/?access_token=xxxxx";
$instagram_follows = json_decode(file_get_contents($instagram))->data->counts->followed_by;
echo $instagram_follows;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function get_https_content($url=NULL,$method="GET"){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    return curl_exec($ch);
}

function ig_count($username) {
    return json_decode(get_https_content("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/1460891826/?client_id=ea69458ef6a34f13949b99e84d79ccf2"))->data->counts->followed_by;
}
```

Here is my code :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one...

```
$url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/USER_ID?access_token=YOUR_TOKEN';
$api_response = file_get_contents($url);
$record = json_decode($api_response);

echo $followed_by = $record->data->counts->followed_by;
```

[Click](http://hkpatel201.blogspot.in/2015/07/login-using-Instagram.html) to get all info of user