# Get Instagram Info using PHP

Tags: php, regex

I want to get Biography from Instagram Account..
I found this- [Getting basic information from Instagram using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414606/getting-basic-information-from-instagram-using-php)

```
$raw = file_get_contents('https://www.instagram.com/USERNAME'); //replace with user
preg_match('/\"followed_by\"\:\s?\{\"count\"\:\s?([0-9]+)/',$raw,$m);
print intval($m[1]);
```

But, I don't really know how to edit it to get bio. Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
user": ({"biography": ".*?")
```

Complete code in PHP

```
$raw = file_get_contents('https://www.instagram.com/USERNAME'); //replace with user
preg_match('/user": ({"biography": ".*?")/',$raw,$m);
$array = json_decode($m[1].'}', true);
echo $array['biography'];
```

Make sure to have `utf-8` encoding for your page

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: It works perfectly! But, for example in- https://www.instagram.com/google/ along with bio, it shows something  like  \u2014 , so, is it possible to remove it? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly! :) Thanks once again! :)