# Instagram is_private regex

Tags: php, regex, instagram

I want to check if a user is private on Instagram. When searching on the internet I found this: [Getting basic information from Instagram using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414606/getting-basic-information-from-instagram-using-php)

```
$raw = file_get_contents('https://www.instagram.com/USERNAME'); 
preg_match('/\"followed_by\"\:\s?\{\"count\"\:\s?([0-9]+)/',$raw,$m);
print intval($m[1]);
```

Which uses a regex to check the number of followers for a user. 
Now I'm trying to use a regex to check if a user is private or not but I'm unable to figure it out. The field is stated in the JSON response as `is_private` but I have not been able to get it working.

Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: Do you really expect us to sign up to Instagram just to learn what is the difference?

Comment: This is `JSON`, so please use appropriate functions like `json_loads()`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your not going to want to do that with Regex, instead check the web page

```
$instagramPage = strip_tags(file_get_contents('http://instagram.com/Username'));
if (strpos($instagramPage,'"is_private":true') !== false) {
    return 'Account is private';
} else {
    return 'Account is public';
}
```