# Display Instagram photos from different account to my webpage

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, instagram

I am looking for the way to display not my instagram photos to my website page, but can't.
Is it possible to do if i have just an account name of the instagram user (e.g. jamieoliver).
My website is written on Wordpress.

Need to display **not my** images

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This URL format `http://instagram.com/{instagram user name}/media` will return a json file with the latest (20+/-) media files from that user.

In the example of `jamieoliver` you can do http://instagram.com/jamieoliver/media

You could process that `json` response through an (jQuery) ajax call like :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://instagram.com/jamieoliver/media",
    dataType : "jsonp", // this is important
    cache: false,
    success: function(response){
        // process the json response to get images
        // e.g. the first image should be something like : 
        // response.items.images[0].low_resolution
        // you could call an external function to iterate through the response
    }
});
```

Of course, I assume you understand what a json format looks like. If you are using WordPress, maybe you could find a plugin to deal with that json response

---

**EDIT**:

It seems like the response from `http://instagram.com/{author_name}/media` is not jsonp but json (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19456236/1055987) for further reference), however setting a json `dataType` will return a cross-domain error.

The workaround is to use [whateverorigin.org](http://whateverorigin.org/) third-party app to circumvent the same-origin policy.

So format your URL like

```
"http://whateverorigin.org/get?url=" + encodeURIComponent("http://instagram.com/{author_name}/media");
```

The `whateverorigin` server will act as proxy and return the proper `json` format.

**Note** that you still need to use `dataType : "jsonp"` in your ajax call.

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/VpGVL/)**

Comment: i am getting an error when trying to get that data                       Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: this is the url returning me                                               http://instagram.com/hestonology/media?callback=jQuery111001328574197832495_1404457655091&_=1404457655092            there is a data, but i always getting an error

Comment: Hey @JSK, is there a way to load more images from that accounts, i want to load more data, by clicking on some button or scrolling down, like here http://hoopshype.com/social/gallery.html#/   , is it possible to do in this way?