# Get instagram's video media source using oembed endpoints

Tags: jquery, ajax, instagram, endpoints, oembed

### THE CONTEXT

I have a piece of (jQuery) ajax code that has been happily working for about 9 months until the last couple of weeks or so.

This code uses Instagram's [embedding endpoints](http://instagram.com/developer/embedding/) that allows me to get the media source (image or video) out of a normal Instagram link like `http://instagram.com/p/BUG/` regardless the user and **without** needing an `access_token`.

Simplified example :

```
var URL = "http://api.instagram.com/oembed?url=http://instagram.com/p/BUG/";
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: URL,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response.url);
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("couldn't process the instagram url");
        }
    });
});
```

In the code above, `response.url` would return the full media URL source like :

```
http://photos-a.ak.instagram.com/xxxx/1234_123456123_123456_n.jpg // image or
http://distilleryvesper3-15.ak.instagram.com/b0c957463548362858_101.mp4 // video
```

Then I could use the returned URL to embed the media file in my webpage.

**NOTE** :

Since the idea is to get the URL source of any Instagram link regardless the user, using [media endpoints](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/#) is not an option.

---

### THE ISSUE

Instagram's oembed endpoints allows you to GET a `json` response, which until the last couple of weeks had this structure :

```
{
    "provider_url" : "http:\/\/instagram.com\/",
    "media_id" : "123456789_123456789",
    "title" : "the title",
    "url" : "http:\/\/photos-a.ak.instagram.com\/hphotos-ak-xfp1\/12345678_123456789012345_1234567890_n.jpg",
    "author_name" : "{the user name}",
    "height" : 640,
    "width" : 640,
    "version" : "1.0",
    "author_url" : "http:\/\/instagram.com\/{the user name}",
    "author_id" : 123456789,
    "type" : "photo",
    "provider_name" : "Instagram"
}
```

As you may noticed, my ajax code was particularly interested in the property name `url`, which contains the full media's URL.

**Notice** that this `json` response (as today) is still valid for Instagram images, **however**, if the original Instagram's link is a video, let's use a real example : http://instagram.com/p/mOFsFhAp4f/ (CocaCola(c)) the `json` response doesn't return any `url` key anymore.

It seems that after the introduction of [web embeds](http://blog.instagram.com/post/55095847329/introducing-instagram-web-embeds) Instagram has decided to replace the key `url` by a `html` property in their (oembed) json response for videos only, which contains the iframe to embed like :

```
{
    ...

    "html" : "\u003ciframe src=\"http:\/\/instagram.com\/p\/BUG\/embed\" width=\"616\" height=\"716\" frameborder=\"0\" scrolling=\"no\" allowtransparency=\"true\"\u003e\u003c\/iframe\u003e",

    ...
}
```

... and of course, that breaks my code since `response.url` is undefined.

---

### THE QUESTION

**How do I get the full video's URL after the changes in the Instagram json response?**

Unfortunately I couldn't find any proper documentation or a change log in Instagram's developers site (they have a great API but poor documentation.)

Please **notice** that the question is about Instagram API (v1) embedding endpoints rather than a jQuery or ajax question.

I am looking for (an undocumented perhaps) Instagram's API option, endpoint, oembed or else (that doesn't require `access_token`) that allows me to retrieve the direct link to the media video (after a json response preferably) out of a normal Instagram link regardless the user ...or willing to consider a not too hacky workaround.

Comment: As I see `BUG` key is a `shortcode` key. have you changed it?

Comment: @MortezaN.Alamdari : please check [Instagram documentation](http://instagram.com/developer/embedding/#) if you knwo what I mean. `BUG` is the shortcode of the media's ID (that can be any like `mOFsFhAp4f` is in http://instagram.com/p/mOFsFhAp4f/ )

Comment: Why don't you check the type of media and then decide whether you need  `response.url` or `response.html` ?

Comment: @Jashwant : sure thing, but `response.html` is an `iframe`. What I am looking for should look like `http://distilleryvesper3-15.ak.instagram.com/b0c957463548362858_101.mp4`. Can you get that out of the `iframe`? (without Firebug of course but from an app ;) If so, please post your answer.

Comment: You do not want to use `embed` link and want a url with `mp4` link ? [This code](http://jsfiddle.net/xAgPS/) will not work for you. Right ?

Comment: @Jashwant : at this point, I am not interested in using iframes (I may end up using them if I have no choice) but I would rather prefer to get the full URL of the mp4 file (so I can use my preferred player like MEJS). An additional issue with embed is: how do you `autoplay`? http://jsfiddle.net/SDRXV/

Comment: @JFK hope my answer is not too hacky for you , i believe it works well for any provided link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE** [March 2015] : For an extended and updated version of this solution, please visit http://www.picssel.com/build-a-simple-instagram-api-case-study/

---

@ProllyGeek's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24593863/1055987) provided a good workaround to scrape the Instagram video page (well deserved bounty), however it relies on the *whateverorigin.org* third-party service, which will work fine unless the service eventually becomes unavailable.

Since the latest already happened to me in a production environment, I had to look for a more reliable alternative so I decided to use php's [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to scrape the video link from an own-hosted PHP module.

I basically followed the same logic proposed by @ProllyGeek but translated to PHP so:

The *getVideoLink.php* module :

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
function clean_input($data){
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = strip_tags($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
};
$instalink = clean_input( $_GET['instalink'] );    
if (!empty($instalink)) {
    $response = clean_input( @ file_get_contents( $instalink ) );
    $start_position = strpos( $response ,'video_url&quot;:&quot;' ); // the start position
    $start_positionlength = strlen('video_url&quot;:&quot;'); // string length to trim before
    $end_position = strpos($response ,'&quot;,&quot;usertags'); // the end position
    $mp4_link = substr( $response, ( $start_position + $start_positionlength ), ( $end_position - ( $start_position + $start_positionlength ) ) );
    echo $mp4_link;
};
?>
```

Of course, you may need to analyze the response manually to know what you are looking for.

Then the AJAX call to the PHP module from my main page :

```
var instaLink = "http://instagram.com/p/mOFsFhAp4f/"; // the Coca Cola video link
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "getVideoLink.php?instalink="+instaLink,
        dataType : "html",
        cache : false,
        success : function (data) {
            console.log(data); // returns http://distilleryvesper3-15.ak.instagram.com/b0ce80e6b91111e3a16a122b8b9af17f_101.mp4
        },
        error : function () {
            console.log("error in ajax");
        }
    });
}); // ready
```

It's assumed your host supports php to use this method.

---

**EDIT** [November 19, 2014]

I have modified the *getVideoLink.php* module (now *getInstaLinkJSON.php*) to actually get the *JSON* information from an specific Instagram media link like `http://instagram.com/p/mOFsFhAp4f/`

This is much more useful than just scraping the video's URL and can be used for images too.

The new *getInstaLinkJSON.php* code :

```
<?php
function clean_input($data){
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = strip_tags($data);
    return $data;
};
// clean user input
function clean_input_all($data){
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = strip_tags($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
};
$instaLink = clean_input_all( $_GET['instaLink'] );

if( !empty($instaLink) ){
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    $response = clean_input( @ file_get_contents($instaLink) );
    $response_length = strlen($response);
    $start_position = strpos( $response ,'window._sharedData = ' ); // the start position
    $start_positionlength = strlen('window._sharedData = '); // string length to trim before
    $trimmed = trim( substr($response, ( $start_position + $start_positionlength ) ) ); // trim extra spaces and carriage returns
    $jsondata = substr( $trimmed, 0, -1); // remove extra ";" added at the end of the javascript variable 
    echo $jsondata;
} elseif( empty($instaLink) ) {
    die(); //only accepts instaLink as parameter
}
?>
```

I am sanitizing both the user's input and the `file_get_contents()` response, however I am not stripping *slashes* or *HTML characters* from the last since I will be returning a *JSON* response.

Then the AJAX call:

```
var instaLink = "http://instagram.com/p/mOFsFhAp4f/"; // demo
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "getInstaLinkJSON.php?instalink=" + instaLink,
    dataType : "json", // important!!!
    cache : false,
    success : function ( response ) {
        console.log( response ); // returns json
        var media = response.entry_data.DesktopPPage[0].media;

        // get the video URL
        // media.is_video : returns true/false

        if( media.is_video ){
            console.log( media.video_url ); // returns http://distilleryvesper3-15.ak.instagram.com/b0ce80e6b91111e3a16a122b8b9af17f_101.mp4
        }
    },
    error : function () {
        console.log("error in ajax");
    }
});
```

---

**EDIT** [May 20, 2020]

currently working PHP

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
function clean_input($data){
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = strip_tags($data);
    return $data;
};
// clean user input
function clean_input_all($data){
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = strip_tags($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
};
$instaLink = clean_input_all( $_GET['instaLink'] );

if( !empty($instaLink) ){
    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    $response = clean_input( @ file_get_contents($instaLink) );
    $response_length = strlen($response);
    $start_position = strpos( $response ,'window._sharedData = ' ); // the start position
    $start_positionlength = strlen('window._sharedData = '); // string length to trim before
    $trimmed = trim( substr($response, ( $start_position + $start_positionlength ) ) ); // trim extra spaces and carriage returns
    $jsondata = substr( $trimmed, 0, -1); // remove extra ";" added at the end of the javascript variable 
    $jsondata = explode('window.__initialDataLoaded', $jsondata);
    echo substr(trim($jsondata[0]), 0, -1);
} elseif( empty($instaLink) ) {
    die(); //only accepts instaLink as parameter
}
?>
```

Comment: im using your answer now for my own issue :D kudos to this solution ;)

Comment: @ProllyGeek : I have improved the code since then, I guess I will post an update any time soon ;)

Comment: please do it asap ty :)

Comment: @ProllyGeek : I did further adjustments in the trimming method

Comment: I'm not sure if they've changed it since then, but this code didn't work for me - even the updated version.  The `$jsondata` variable returned a bunch of html `<script>` tags that meant that it wasn't valid JSON.  I had to trim it slightly differently:  `$pos1 = strpos($response,'window._sharedData = ');
     $trim1 = trim(substr($response, ($pos1 + 21)));
     $pos2 = strpos($trim1,"</script>");
     $trim2 = trim(substr($trim1,0,$pos2-1));
     $jsondata = json_decode($trim2);`

Comment: @Chud37 please refer to http://www.picssel.com/build-a-simple-instagram-api-case-study/ which has updated information (haven't had time to update this answer)

Answer (score 6):

This may not be the best or optimum answer , but as i believe this will solve your issue for now , so you may consider it a work around:

Thanks to whateverorigin.org service we are able to fetch cross origin json , which has all the data you may request , all you have to do is converting the returned object to string , then use regex to fetch whatever data you need.

```
var myvideourl="http://instagram.com/p/mOFsFhAp4f/"
$.ajaxSetup({
    scriptCharset: "utf-8", //maybe "ISO-8859-1"
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
});

$.getJSON('http://whateverorigin.org/get?url=' + 
    encodeURIComponent(myvideourl) + '&callback=?',
    function(data) {

        var xx=data.contents
        var dataindex=xx.search('<meta property="og:video" content=')
        var end=xx.indexOf('/>', dataindex);
        var yy=xx.slice(dataindex,end+2)
        var metaobject=$.parseHTML(yy)
        alert(metaobject[0].content)
        console.log(metaobject[0].content)
});
```

Here is and example:

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/prollygeek/j53sz/1/)

works well for me , but only tried it on the CocaCola video , havent tried it on other links.

Comment: Beautiful. Ironically I have used `whateverorigin.org` for other solutions, including this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/24559815/1055987 but it didn't cross my mind for this specific scenario. I am reluctant to use third-party services since they may stop working any time. The good thing is that `whateverorigin` is open source so I could host the service myself for my client's needs. Kudos for your answer, I just need to make some considerations and wait for other possible answers before granting any bounty ;)

Comment: ok no problem , just hope i could help , good luck finding the best answer :)

Comment: an alternative that may or may not be less likely to go down is `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/`

Answer (score 0):

I am not a jQuery expert. Putting aside the syntax error(s), could this be any use?

```
var publicUrl = "http://instagram.com/p/dAu7UPgvn0"; //photo
var publicUrl = "http://instagram.com/p/mOFsFhAp4f"; //video


var URL = "http://api.instagram.com/oembed?url="+publicUrl;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: URL,
        publicurl: publicUrl,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) {
            success: function (response) {
                var mediaSrc;
                if (response.type === 'photo') {
                    mediaSrc = response.url;
                } else {
                    mediaSrc = $(publicurl).find('div.Video vStatesHide Frame').src;
                }
                console.log(mediaSrc);
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("couldn't process the instagram url");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This is similar to my answer :)

`$(publicurl).find('div.Video vStatesHide Frame').src` is incorrect. Either you can use `[0].src` like me, or you can use `attr('src')`

Comment: @Jashwant I am sure it is ;). But unlike your method, I am not suggesting to rely on api returns. It is more like web scrapping since the op is quite desperate to get the actual source.

Comment: You cannot scrape it like this. See Prolly's answer.

Comment: Instagram has removed type as `photo` or `video`, now it returns `rich` for type field

Comment: http://www.picssel.com/build-a-simple-instagram-api-case-study/ provided link is not working