# How do I reference data from an getJSON/ajax out of scope?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, instagram

I'm trying to return a string of an Instagram API url. Not an object, not the data, but when `getUrl()` is called, it returns a string which I can then use in a getJSON later on.

The tricky bit is, thanks to the Instagram API, I first need to generate the user ID from the username (that's the getJSON you see, which works fine by the way), store that ID as user_id, then insert that ID into my string.

I understand what I have at the moment isn't working because ajax is async, and also because user_id is being used out of scope. So my question is.. what do I need to do? I feel like I'm close.

```
var username = foo;
var client_id = 1234567890;

function getUrl() {    

  function getUserID() {
    return 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=' + username + '&amp;callback=?&amp;client_id=' + client_id;
  }

  $.getJSON(getUserID(), function (data) {
    var user_id = data.data[0].id;
  });

  return 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/' + user_id + '/media/recent/?&client_id=' + client_id;

}

console.log(getUrl);
```

Comment: what is the `console log` output?

Comment: @MortezaEdalati Uncaught ReferenceError: user_id is not defined.

Comment: check if return is running before the ajax call has completed

Comment: @saj Yes, it is, due to ajax being async - is there a way around this other than making it sync?

Comment: answer below should work fine

Comment: If you already have the username, do you really need to get `user_id`? What I mean is, there are other ways to get the recent media from an Instagram user without even needing `access_token`, `user_id` or `client_id` (and without bothering with synchronous ajax calls)

Comment: @JFK That sounds ideal, do you have any links? I've not seen anything like that.

Comment: @Jake : Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/24559815/1055987, mostly the last edit (includes demo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is write a callback function that'll use the result of your ajax call. This function will receive the proper url from the asynchronous call inside `getUrl()`, so add whatever code that needs the url at your callback function and it'll be executed right after the `$.getJSON` finishes.

```javascript
var username = foo;
var client_id = 1234567890;

function getUrl(getURLCallBack) {
    var user_id = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=' + username + '&amp;callback=?&amp;client_id=' + client_id;

    $.getJSON(user_id, function (data) {
        user_id = data.data[0].id;
        var url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/' + user_id + '/media/recent/?&client_id=' + client_id;
        //Your callback function will do the magic for you
        getURLCallBack(url);
    });
}

//In this example, f will be your callback
f = function (url) {
    alert(url);
}

getUrl(f);
```

Comment: If you really need like this, you can make your ajax call synchronous. [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6685294/3465182) has everything you need to know. Please note, though, that this is against AJAX's nature and I try avoiding it (The A in AJAX stands for asynchronous, after all)